# How to resolve Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a live site and I open it on Internet explorer and right click on page and click on view source and copy all code from it and paste it on vs2010->Newwebsite and when i run my site on vs2010 an error occur.

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

I don't understand what I do. Kindly suggest me.
waiting for reply.
Thanks

Comment: Did you include jquery.min.js file on top?

Comment: include jquery $ is a jquery symbol so u have to include the one if u wanna use it

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd fix that by including jQuery!

Add the following to your page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, it sounds like just an error in Visual Studio, and if it works when viewing the page in a browser, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: or any other script that provides $ as global variable.

Comment: @AdamMoszczyński - The question is tagged jQuery, so I assumed the $ was jQuery. Could be a number of other things, scripts overwriting $, noConflict mode, as in Wordpress etc.

Comment: @HassanAliKhan - Then it's not loading, or you're not including before you're trying to use it, or $ is overwritten by something else. Is this just in VS2010, or in the browser as well.

Comment: @HassanAliKhan: Check that you have that Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js on the server

Comment: @HassanAliKhan:- If your script is in a Scripts directory then you just use Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js because with a web server, everything is within it's root (top level) directory.

Answer (score 0):

First verify that jQuery is in fact being loaded.

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
  alert("jQuery is loaded!");
}
```

If that works, then you are most likely using something like `jQuery.noconflict()` to remove the alias `$` for jQuery.